# Why can't I use # ( Number Sign ) as a value in POST ( php page )

Tags: php, post, http-post

I have a php project where I have to pass file name as POST request to delete files in web server.But while I pass file name containing # ( Number Sign ) it is unable to get correct file name which resulting error.

here is my simple php script

```
<?php
$file = $_GET["file"];
if (!unlink("upload/".$file))
  {
  echo ("Error deleting $file");
  }
else
  {
  echo ("Deleted $file");
  }
?>
```

Comment: This seems like a very very bad idea. `$_GET['file'] = '../../../../../../../etc/passwd';`

Comment: @MikeB Thanks for warning. Above php code used just for local server environment for my collage project.

Comment: Nobody with access to a collage server has ever thought it would be funny to exploit a security hole and break someone else's project. It is well know that collage students are the most mature form of human being.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because:

- You are trying to read from `$_GET` not `$_POST` *and*
- `#` has special meaning in URIs and must be percent encoded as `%23` if you want to express it as data